# Which Routers Support Logging How Long A Laptop Has Been Connected?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I want to be able to measure the hours spent on a laptop that is connected to my WiFi.

I don't need to know anything about the traffic itself, I just want to know how long the computer has been turned on and connected.

Are there any routers out there that support that capability? Which ones?

Comment: On Super User questions about hardware capabilities are off-topic as hardware capabilities change and preference and opinion can play an important and valid part in such answers.

Comment: You might be able to set this up on anything that can run OpenWrt (and probably other aftermarket open source router firmware distros) by using RADIUS Accounting.

Comment: I ended up remembering that a device I have called "Circle with Disney" offers the capability via its "Insights" feature, so I'm currently trying to use that. Thanks for the advice, all!

Answer (score 1):

A laptop only connected by wifi is only seen by it's traffic.
logging on a router will slow it down.
look for a router that will send emails, and will notify you this way.
I like my AVM Fritz! 7490 for this, it will also notify me about incoming regular calls on my voip account.

Comment: Any idea of a good place to buy one in the United States?